# I want a user who made request from example.com to mydomain.example/domains to redirect to mydomain.com/userdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, request, httprequest, vanity-url

I want a user who made request from `example.com` to `mydomain.example/domains` to redirect to `mydomain.example/userdomain`. It is like implementing vanity URLs as per the user's domain name.
I know, we can do it using `.htaccess` redirect rules but don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've EDITED the following code as best I can without a way to test it.  It should get you close if it doesn't work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) mydomain.example/%1/$1 [L]
```

should do the trick.  Can't test it quickly myself though.  There are two key things to notice:
You gotta use HTTP_HOST  in a RewriteCond to test the domain.  Use %1 in the RewriteRule line to get the variable from the HTTP_HOST line in parentheses.

You also gotta redirect any requests to www to the non www with an R=301 permanent redirect first.  It might be possible NOT to do this, but I'm not sure at the moment how to extract the non www part of the host regardless of its presence.  The R=301 sends a redirect msg back to the browser for anyone who visits `www.example.com`.  Then the browser will hit `example.com` and your second `RewriteRule` will match against it.  Since its 301 (permanent) the browser will cache the redirect and always do the non-www for the user on its own.

If this doesn't work, compare to some other tutorials on URL redirection and also refer to this wonderful page:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html

Comment: My apologies, I edited the code above further to make it as best I could without having tested.  Best of luck if noone else responds!

Comment: Doesn't this result in a redirect loop? `userdomain.com/test`=>`mydomain.com/userdomain.com/test`=>`mydomain.com/mydomain.com/userdomain.com/test` etc.

Comment: It shouldn't.  The first Cond/Rule pair rewroute anything matching www.something.com to something.com.   It will happen once since something.com won't get redirected when its missing the www.  The second condition/rule pair will pick up on something.com and transfer it internally to mydomain.com/something.com/    Are we following each other?

Comment: Note that the second pair is an "internal redirect" that tells Apache where to fetch the files for the requestion URI. It's not an actual browser redirect like the first pair.

Comment: Your correct, assuming that userdomain.com and mydomain.com are not pointing to the same vhost (which I assumed)

Comment: Thanks Jim. I haven't really implemented it to test but as per what I could understand from the code, I think it would do the work.